# How to show subcategories in magento like refer website?

Tags: magento-1.9

Here , Parent category is Chairs.
& subcategories are modern, classic, patio, event....etc.
Like this website: http://www.example.com

there are categories With images at the top under refine text

How to show these subcategory in category page with images in magento.

Comment: See my updated answer to get subcategoies with image

Comment: are you got my answer?

Comment: yes, second way is working

Comment: hi, can u checked code once again,  pls check echo $subcategory->getUrl()

Answer (score 2):

This will help to get child category with Image of every current category

> app/design/frontend/package/theme/template/catalog/category/view.phtml

**First Way:** By current category:

```
<?php 
  $layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
  $_category = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
  $currentCategoryId= $_category->getId();
  $children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($currentCategoryId);
?>
<?php foreach ($children as $category): ?>
      <a href="<?php echo $subcategory->getUrl() ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo $subcategory->getImageUrl(); ?>" />
      </a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**Second Way:** By category ID:

```
<?php
  $categoryId = 10 ;  // get current category id
  $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId) ;
  $catList = explode(",", $category->getChildren();) ;
?>
<?php foreach($catList as $cat): ?>
     <?php $subcategory = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category')->load($cat); ?>
     <a href="<?php echo $subcategory->getUrl() ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo $subcategory->getImageUrl(); ?>" />
     </a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```